# What is sourceindex

Tags: html

In quite a few content editors, I see code generated that includes attributes of the form

```
sourceindex=
```

What is this attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the [`sourceIndex` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page on the MSDN and the lack of any mention of `sourceIndex` at W3.org, I believe it is a proprietary Microsoft tag (and unlikely to be supported - or considered valid X/HTML - by non-Microsoft browsers).

Comment: It is found in a Joomla and Mambo also, so perhaps it is not a proprietary Microsoft tag, unless all the Joomla/Mambo template developers are developing in MS Word.  :P

Comment: @Steve - Why would the use of proprietary HTML attributes mean that an application was developed *with* Microsoft software?

Comment: Good question, but what would they need it for?  Internet Explorer?

Comment: @Steve - Primarily Internet Explorer but, theoretically, any Microsoft .NET application that parses HTML could access the `sourceIndex` property of an element. If you want to see how the `sourceIndex` attribute might be used in IE, this article at quirksmode.org includes some examples: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getElementsByTagNames.html